# IVP $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{y}, y(0)=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

How many solutions does the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{y}, x>0$ with the initial condition $y(0)=0$ have? It is clear that zero is one of its solutions. However, when we attempt to solve it, we arrive at $\sqrt{y}=\frac{-x}{2}$ which is not a possible solution. How can we determine the number of solutions for this initial value problem (IVP)? If it has a unique solution, why is that the case? If it has infinitely many solutions, could you please provide at least one non-zero solution? Thank you.

Comment: You need the $+C$ somewhere in your solution.

Comment: I am confused you have initial condition $y(x=0) = 0$ and $x > 0$ ?

Comment: @Paul $C=0$ by the initial condition.

Comment: Hint: what can be said about monotonicity of each possible solution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: @Yalikesifulei mint decreasing.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei what will be answer sir ?

Comment: @neelkanth you need to combine this property with given initial condition and what you already know about possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly reason that the only solution is the zero solution. Your question of "why" is not very clear. A priori there is no "reason" that an equation does or does not have a solution - it just does or doesn't.

In this case, though, there is a relatively satisfying answer. Equations of the form $y' = f(y)$ are guaranteed to have a unique solution by the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) *provided* that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. In the case $f(y) = -\sqrt{y}$, $f$ does not have this property (can you show why?).

Note that in the case $f(y) = \sqrt{y}$, the theorem *still* doesn't apply, but there *are* non-zero solutions. So just having the conditions fail does not imply there are no solutions. The reason there are no solutions is the argument you provide in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, this ODE doesn't have a unique solution. The step that is needed to quantify the number of solutions, lies in the fact that the equation is autonomous, hence "time invariant". This means that the particular solution $$\begin{equation}
  y(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{x^2}{2} & \text{if $x>0$}\\
      0 & \text{if $x\le0$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}$$

is valid in a more general setting:
$$\begin{equation}
  y(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{(x-\chi)^2}{2} & \text{if $x>\chi$}\\
      0 & \text{if $x\le\chi$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}$$

From the information provided in the problem, so only the initial value, we cannot determine the value of $\chi$. This means that the equation has infinitely many solutions!

To give you more insights about this equation, if we consider $x$ to be the time $t$, we can say that there could be more than one future since we can't predict the time at which "the function changes". Indeed, with the equation $y''=\sqrt{y}$ (note that it's now 2nd order) we can actually show that Newtonian mechanics is non-deterministic. If you're interested, read about Norton's dome.

Comment: is it satisfying given Differential equation?

Comment: Yes, it does. By the way, I put a typo: the solution should be over 4, not over 2.

Comment: How can $\frac{x^2}{2}$ satisfies $y'=-\sqrt{y}?$

Comment: It's a separable ODE, which we can solve with traditional methods. Namely $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{y}\implies \int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=-\int dx\implies 2\sqrt{y}=-x+c\implies \sqrt{y}=\frac{-x+c}{2}\implies y(x)=\frac{(-x+c)^2}{4}$

Plugging in the initial condition you find $c=0$, so the solution is $y(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}$

Comment: if $c=0$, then $\sqrt{y}=\frac{-x}{2}$, which is not possible as square root function is non negative.

Comment: I understand your problem and I honestly believe that I cannot provide you with a satisfactory answer. What I can tell you is that if you assume that to be true, and if you consider the solution $y(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}$, then $y'=\frac{x}{2}$. But $\frac{x}{2} = -\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)=-\sqrt{y}$. 

So $y'\equiv -\sqrt{y}$. This means that the function is a solution to the ODE.